# Как изменить цвет материала/текстуры в Unity, после импорта модели из Блендера?

Tags: unity3d

Делаю всё как в видео, и на [10.22](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AOoqt92IEcc) вручную регулируют цвет. Но у меня по каким-то причинам эта функция не активна, как и все остальные.

Не реагирует.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать, чтобы реагировала?

Comment: Нужно извлечь текстуры и материалы вашей модели. В данном видео подробно все описано[enter link description here](https://youtu.be/m3ufW7Q3Tr8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выбираем модель и выбираем вкладку `Materials`. Затем в строке `Location` выставляем `Use External Materials (Legacy)`. После чего подтверждаем изменение настроек кнопкой `Apply`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я понял, этим действием `Unity` создаёт отдельную папку и выкидывает туда наши материалы/текстуры из модели.

После этого можно изменить цветовую гамму нашего материала/текстуры по вашему усмотрению.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я перевёл цвет в белый, в следствии чего - модель приобрела свой первоначальный цвет.

Answer (score 0):

- Нужно извлечь текстуры и материалы вашей модели.

  1 Выбрать вашу модель в окне Project

  2. В окне Inspector перейти на вкладку Materials
  3. Создать папку и извлечь в нее текстуры вашей модели (Extract Textures)
  4. То же самое проделать с материалами модели (Extract Materials)
  5. Выбрать вашу модель в окне сцены и раскрыть его на компоненты
  6. Выбираем каждый компонет модели и в окне Inspector в разделе Shaders изменяем параметр с "Standart" на "Legasy Shaders/Deffuse
     Detail"
  7. Наслаждаемся результатом.

[Источник ответа](https://youtu.be/m3ufW7Q3Tr8)